# how to append string

Tags: shell

I am parsing a file to get the selected string and build into a single line, however, I don't know how to do it(as shown in //add...) in shell scripts

```
while read line
do
    tt=`echo $line | cut -d'|' -f2 | cut -d'"' -f1`
    //add a $total = add all tt parts into a big string seperate by ", "
done < tmp_file

echo $total >> outfile
```

thank you

Comment: Just echo whatever in `tt` (plus comma) to the output?

Comment: i need to build one line($total) for each file, and that line is made with many $tt pieces.

Comment: It is possible to not print a new line with `echo`. Just that my idea will incur quite a large number of disk access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You append in the shell using assignment and variable expansion:

```
total="${total}, ${tt}"
```

The curly braces (`{}`) aren't necessary in this case but I find they help distinguish variables when they're next to each other like this.

This will give you a leading ", ".  You can work around it like this:

```
total="${total:+${total}, }${tt}"
```

The `${variable:+value}` construct only expands to `value` if `variable` is set.

Answer (score 0):

The Code have to be like this i think ^_^"

```
while read line

do

    $tt=`echo $line | cut -d'|' -f2 | cut -d'"' -f1`

    $total .= $tt.", ";

done < tmp_file

echo $total >> outfile
```

i think that's all ^^ :D just a concatenation with a point missed  :p lol :D